# Make sure all dependencies are open

Tags: android, eclipse, shared-libraries

My co-worker sent me an Eclipse Android project for me to continue working on it. I want to export it to use it on Android Studio, but when I go to Eclipse and Export, I get the error that the project (path name)gridlayout_v7 is missing. Needed by my project and to make sure that all dependencies are open.

I worked with Android and Eclipse several times before and never had this problem, and I'm a bit tired of importing the library, showing where it is, whatever, and this stupid thing continues to complain that it's not there.

Some clue?